# Looking for QGIS processing script equivalent of ST_Buffer

Tags: pyqgis, buffer

I have a shapefile layer containing road data and some of the data has entries for both carriageways, the data only has a road name so no way to distinguish between them. I've created a script that joins roads with the same name where they meet, which in many cases leaves me with two geometries and sometimes many due to no linear sections, bad data ...

I need to consistently identify one side of the road. As part of that I would like to find lines that have a parallel line, in PostGIS I could use st_buffer to the lines and identify the parallel lines based of their intersections.

I can't find anything in the documentation on any equivalents for ST_Buffer, ST_Area or ST_Intersection  and was wondering if someone would know.  To complicate matters I'm using I'm using GQIS 2.18

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are mentioning SQL `ST_Buffer`, I will pretend you are using PyQGIS.

At the **layer** level, you can use QGIS Processing.

```
import processing
processing.run("qgis:buffer", # get the list of params for a QGIS 2 script here, I can't check)
```

Link for QGIS Processing in QGIS 2.18 : https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/processing/console.html#id1

In QGIS 3, the algorithm is called `native:buffer`.

At the **feature** level, with a `QgsGeometry`, you can use `buffer()` : https://api.qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsGeometry.html#af35db5f3d89c035597b0bdcb7924510c